# How to determine which OAuth2ResourceServer flow the user has configured

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-oauth2

I am building a wrapper framework over springboot (2.3.3.RELEASE). The clients can configure OAuth2 resource server to validate either JWT or Opaque token based on the below:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, securedEnabled = true)
public class ResourceServerExampleApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ResourceServerExampleApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Configuration
    static class SampleOAuth2WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated();
//            .and()
//                .oauth2ResourceServer().jwt();
//                .oauth2ResourceServer().opaqueToken();

           ...
        }
```

From inside my wrapper application framework, how do I determine what the user has configured above? I mean, I want to programmatically detect if the user has configured `JWT` or `Opaque Token` flow and do different things based on that. I have looked into Spring code and found the class `org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.oauth2.server.resource.OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer` being used to configure either `JwtConfigurer` or `OpaqueTokenConfigurer` at runtime.

Unfortunately, this class is marked `final` and I cannot extend it and customize it. Any pointers on how to handle my requirement?